# check url if valid or not with preg_match and RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Can anyone tell me what is the RegEx of this url http://ask.fm/malakFR/answer/109993073781

If I want to use it with [`preg_match`](http://uk.php.net/preg_match) to check if url is valid or not.

Comment: Look into `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` for generic URL validation.

Comment: Regexes are not a magic wand that you wave at every problem that involves strings.  Plus, validation of URLs is a solved problem that you do not need to solve yourself.  You use existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: What is a valid url for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the concrete link

`/http:\/\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\.[a-zA-Z]{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{7}\/[a-zA-Z]{6}\/\d{12}/`

to online test-> http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

if you want to understand what I did (at the bottom of the page is a cheat-sheet) http://regex101.com/

p.s: this pattern will work just for the link you gave, can' guarantee for others will work, read the cheat-sheet